# What is the language of the manuscripts of the Book of Dede Korkut?

Tags: the-book-of-dede-korkut

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Book_of_Dede_Korkut&oldid=948663348), the *Book of Dede Korkut* is written in "Oghuz Turkish", a language name that does not have its own article on Wikipedia and that is not documented on Ethnologue.
Wikipedia has an article about the [Oghuz languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oghuz_languages), a sub-branch of the Turkic languages.
The Western Oghuz languages include Turkish, Azerbaijani and the now defunct Ottoman Turkish.
Searching "Oghuz" on [Ethnologue](https://www.ethnologue.com/) only gives two results,
one for a dialect of Uzbek (on the Karluk branch, not the Oghuz branch of the Turkic languages) and one for a dialect of Udi (a Northeast Caucasian language),
neither of which seem relevant to the language of the *Book of Dede Korkut*.

Wikipedia categorizes the *Book of Dede Korkut* as [Azerbaijani literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_literature#The_epic_tradition) and says it was "written in Azerbaijani language" (Source: V. Barthold: *The book of my grandfather Korkut*. Moscow and Leningrad: USSR Academy of Sciences, 1962).
Wikipedia describes [two manuscripts of the *Book of Dede Korkut*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Book_of_Dede_Korkut&oldid=948663348#Manuscript_tradition): one found in the Royal Library of Dresden and one discovered in the Vatican Library in 1950.
According to Geoffrey Lewis, who published a translation in 1974, these manuscripts date from the 16th century (the stories as such are older).
The Dresden manuscript contains twelve stories, while the Vatican manuscript contains six stories.

The website of the [International Symposium of Dede Korkut, June 2020](https://sempozyum.sdu.edu.tr/dedekorkut/en/yeni_el_yazmasi_hakkinda.html) mentions a recently discovered third manuscript:

> In addition to these writings, the third Dede Korkut manuscript was found in the Turkmen Sahara region of Iran. This third manuscript has been named as the **Turkmen Sahara** copy regarding its location.
>   In this third manuscript, which is missing an unknown amount from the beginning, there are twenty-seven extollings that weren't mentioned in previous manuscripts.

(A scanned version of this third manuscript can be found on [Library Genesis](http://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=6E4E6F9FE6DDD6130D13B4EB5A81D88E).)

Confusingly, the [Staats- und Universitätsbibliothek Dresden (SLUB)](https://www.slub-dresden.de/en/collections/manuscripts/kitab-i-dedem-korkut/) describes the Dresden manuscript as "written in Arab language", which is not even a Turkic language.
(Possibly, the librarians confused the [Arabic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script), used by several Turkic languages, with the Arabic language.)
When you click through to [view the manuscript](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/werkansicht/dlf/10013/1/), the metadata identify the language as "Alttürkisch", which refers to a time period from the 7th to 13th century (see Wikipedia: [Alttürkisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altt%C3%BCrkische_Sprache) and [Old Turkic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Turkic_language)).

So far, the only clear statement about the language of the *Book of Dede Korkut* is Barthold's claim that the text was written in Azerbaijani.
Does this apply to each of the extant manuscripts of the *Book of Dede Korkut*?

Comment: This question is currently not tagged with [tag:turkish-literature], [tag:azerbaijani-literature] or [tag:oghuz-turkic-literature] (see [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54052525#54052525)) because that would imply that the question has already been answered.

Comment: @kimchilover According to Wikipedia, [Alttürkisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altt%C3%BCrkische_Sprache) covers the 7th-13th centuries, while Lewis dates the story to the late fourteenth to fifteenth centuries. Maybe the librarians weren't too sure ...

Comment: Librarians' categorizations and Wikipedia's categorizations are time-varying and both, in effect, whimsical. For all I know, the SLUB's description is that of von Dietz from 1815.  Maybe the linguistics SE would be a better place for your question?  Remember the quip that the difference between a language and a dialect is that the former has an army.

Comment: @kimchilover I remember that quip. Weren't those nomadic Oghuz people an army on the move? ;-)

Comment: In the ancient past, sure.  In 1815, there was an Ottoman army but not an Oghuz or Azeri one.  In 1972 there was no Azeri one, but nowadays there is.

Comment: Based on the answers, I have now added the tag [tag:turkish-literature].

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article seems largely based on Lewis's book, which predates the discovery of the third MS. Lewis says (on p.22 of the Penguin edition)

> As to the language of the text, it is consistent with the book's belonging to the late fourteenth or early fifteenth century. It exhibits a number of features charactersitic of Azeri, the Turkish dialect of Azerbaijan, side by side with certain western features, the latter being more frequent in the Vatican M.S. The origins of the text lie back in the time before Azeri and Ottoman emerged as separate dialects. But it is unwise to try to draw conclusions from linguistic evidence about the time or place of the compilation of the book, as we cannot know whether any given feature is due to the compiler or to subsequent bards and copyists.

I cannot imagine the third MS invalidates the last sentence here.

It is worth noting that the Dresden MS *says* it is written in Oghuz Turkish, which might partly answer the OP's question.  Diez's 1815 article [DepéGhöz oder der 
 oghuzische Cyklop](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101075165686&view=1up&seq=7) [=*Tepegöz, the Oghuz Cyclops*"] starts out with

> Die Handschrift, woraus ich den gegenwärtigen  Aufsatz nehmen, ist auf der Schmutzseite des ersten Blatts überschriben: [....]
>   Das ist, Buch der Dedé Korkud in der Sprache des Volks  der Oghuzier.

[= The manuscript this essay is about bears, on the verso side of the first leaf, the inscription [....] which is to say "'The Book of Dede Korkut' in the language of the Oghuz people".]

Comment: "*The origins of the text lie back in the time before Azeri and Ottoman emerged as separate dialects.*" Which of course makes it a headache for us on this site to decide which language tag to use :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I would take this as a hint that the tag system is possibly over thought.

Answer (score 1):

Hayrettin İhsan Erkoç of the Faculty of Sciences and Arts at Çanakkale Onsekiz Mart University wrote (emphasis mine):

> The Dresden and Vatican manuscripts are written in **Old Anatolian Turkish** showing marks of Eastern Anatolian accents; they are most probably from the **mid-16th century**. ([Twitter, 11.04.2020](https://twitter.com/h_ihsan_erkoc/status/1249073759526453248))
>   
> The **latest discovered manuscript** is also written in the same language but the calligraphy indicates that it was most probably copies in the **18th century**. ([Twitter, 11.04.2020](https://twitter.com/h_ihsan_erkoc/status/1249073783589257217)

This contradicts the metadata provided by the [Staats- und Universitätsbibliothek Dresden (SLUB)](https://digital.slub-dresden.de/werkansicht/dlf/10013/1/0/), where the Dresden manuscript has been digitised.

Note that Wikipedia classifies [Old Turkic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Turkic_language) as a [Siberian Turkic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_Turkic_languages), while it classifies [Old Anatolian Turkish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Anatolian_Turkish) as an Oghuz [Turkic] language. The Wikipedia article on Old Anatolian Turkish contains a few examples of differences of the Arabic script used for Old Anatolian Turkish and the later Ottoman Turkish, including the word "dede". In Old Anatolian Turkish: دَدَ‎;
in Ottoman Turkish: دده.

[Heinrich Friedrich von Diez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Friedrich_von_Diez) (1751 -1817), who published the first translation of the Dresden manuscript in 1815 (see [Depé Ghöz oder der oghuzische Cyklop](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101075165686&view=1up&seq=7)), described the language as "Tatarisch-Türkisch", i.e. Tatar-Turkic ([Tatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatar_language) being another Turkic language that does not belong on the Oghuz sub-branch). Since linguistics has evolved a lot in the last 200 years, I trust Hayrettin İhsan Erkoç's judgement over Diez's.

Hayrettin İhsan Erkoç added in a third tweet,

> Old Anatolian Turkish is a part of Middle Turkic and it is a dialect of Oghuz Turkic dating to the 13th-15th centuries. Oghuz itself was a dialect of the Old Turkic language that lasted until the 13th century. ([Twitter, 11.04.2020](https://twitter.com/h_ihsan_erkoc/status/1249074400919531520))